# Sourcecode combinatorics

Tags: code-golf

Objective:

> The task is to create two programs using the same or different
>   programming languages. The sourcecodes will be combined in two
>   different ways and the resulting sourcecodes can be in any programming
>   languages. The four programs (original two + the two combinations)
>   should output different things.

Rules:

1. Your programs (all four) should not take any input (from user, filename, network or anything).
2. The first program should output exactly `Hello`, nothing else.
3. The second program should output exactly `world`, nothing else.
4. The first combinated program should output `Hello human!`, nothing else.
5. The second combinated program should output `Hello computer!`, nothing else.

Here is how the two combinated programs may be created:

**First combined program**:

- Choose **two** numbers (equal or different) between 1 and 6 (that is: 2, 3, 4 or 5), the two numbers are called: `n1` and `n2`.
- Copy `n1` number of characters from the first program and paste into the combined sourcecode
- Copy `n1` number of characters from the second program and paste into the combined sourcecode
- Copy `n2` number of characters from the first program and paste into the combined sourcecode
- Copy `n2` number of characters from the second program and paste into the combined sourcecode
- Next, start over copy `n1` number of characters again and so on. Copy from start to end from the sourcecodes, paste from start to end into the combined sourcecode.

**Second combined program**:

- The sourcecode is the reverse of the first combined program sourcecode above. You may replace up to 3 characters at any place afterwards (optional). You can replace the up to 3 characters with any other characters. Replacing means 1 char for 1 char at up to 3 different positions on the sourcecode. The final sourcecode size in characters should therefor be exactly the same size as the first combined program size.

**Example** creating the combinated programs using numbers 3 and 4:

```
            First program:    {'Hello'}:p
           Second program:    /*         */ console.log ("World");
 First combinated program:    {'H/* ello    '}:   */ console.log ("World");
Second combinated program:    ;)"dlroW"( gol.elosnoc /*   :}'    olle */H'}
```

Be sure to declare all four programming languages that you use (even if they are all the same) and what numbers you have used when creating the first combinated sourcecode.

This is code-golf, shortest code in bytes for the two sourcecodes wins! Good luck, have fun!

Comment: +1. Your challenges are crazy; you make us work really hard on short pieces of code, you impose strict requirements, etc.

Comment: I'm going to guess it has to work for only 1 chosen combination of numbers, not all combinations? Also, if one of the programs runs out of characters during combination procedure, is the remainder of the other program just appended?

Comment: Yes, only 1 number combination needs to work and yes if one code run out of chars, the rest of the pther is appended last on first combinated source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Befunge-98 × 4, 69 chars

Following @user12551's lead, I went with 4× Befunge (although -98 rather than -93).  Program code is reversed on byte-level, line ending is `LF`, program #1 has no terminating newline.

**Program 1**:

```
"!namolleH"4k,@
```

**Program 2**:

```
"vdlrow"4k,@
      >"uh olleH"bk,@,ke"Hello computer!"
```

**Combined 1** (*n₁ = 5*, *n₂ = 2*):

```
"!nam"volleHdl"4k,@row"4k,@
      >"uh olleH"bk,@,ke"Hello computer!"
```

**Combined 2** (has a bunch of trailing spaces):

```
"!retupmoc olleH"ek,@,kb"Hello hu">      
@,k4"wor@,k4"ldHellov"man!"
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Befunge-93 x4; n1=5, n2=5; <strike>100</strike> 75 chars

I put the 4 programs into 1 file for debugging:  (it outputs a random one of the four programs)

```
 vv  |2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|23
>??#@"oll""eH"   >:#0#,_ @    #
     |2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|23
>? #@"dlr""ow"        >:#0#,_ @0"!namuh olleH">:#,_@#:>"Hello computer!"
     |2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|23
 > #@"oll""dlr""eH" "ow"   >:#     0#,_   >:#@    0#,_ #@0"!namuh olleH">:#,_@#:>"Hello computer!"
     |2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|2345|23
  >#@"!retupmoc olleH">:#,_@#:>"Hello human!"0@# _,#0    @#:>   _,#0     #:>   "wo" "He""rld""llo"
```

The separate programs are: (one per line)

```
"oll""eH"   >:#0#,_ @    #
"dlr""ow"        >:#0#,_ @0"!namuh olleH">:#,_@#:>"Hello computer!"
"oll""dlr""eH" "ow"   >:#     0#,_   >:#@    0#,_ #@0"!namuh olleH">:#,_@#:>"Hello computer!"
"!retupmoc olleH">:#,_@#:>"Hello human!"0@# _,#0    @#:>   _,#0     #:>   "wo" "He""rld""llo"
```

Edit:  This time, I took advantage of the replacement rule and replaced two characters in the second combination.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Command script x4; n1=2; n2=2 - 92 Bytes

1st script (marked eol and eof):

```
 %: !rupc leoh %\r\n
 % eo llhun!% \r\n
 %echo Hello\eof
```

2nd script (marked eol and eof):

```
 %&&etmoolH ce %\r\n
 %chHeo ma% % \r\n
echo world%  \eof
```

Results in:

```
 % %: &&!retupmoc olleH ohce % %
 % % echo Hello human!% % % 
 %ecechoho w Horelldlo%
```

And reversed:

```
 %oldlleroH w ohohcece% 
 % % %!namuh olleH ohce % % 
% % echo Hello computer!&& :% %
```